# Can't access Model inside webform ascx file

Tags: javascript, webforms, sitecore, ascx, web-forms-for-marketers

I am trying to do a simple console log of a ascx model in the view of my presentation file.

```
<script>
    console.log("hello world", <%=Model%>);
</script>
```

I have defined the Model on line one as so

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Guide.ascx.cs" Inherits="Guide.Presentation.Form" %>
```

And for goodness sake, here is the code behind

```
namespace Guide.Presentation
{
    public partial class Form : ModelBoundUserControl<Model.Form>
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

The console log in the top comes out as

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Form' of undefined

Meaning that the Presentation property is undefined. 
Is there anything wrong in the way I have setup the model in the ascx file? or is this a problem with the Sitecore model from which we get the data? Any ideas to what is happening?

Comment: Are you trying to extend Web Forms for Marketeers, or do you want to create a "normal" ascx Sitecore (sub) layouts?  tip, If it is possible use MVC instead of webForms.

Comment: @JanBluemink The projekt is too established to convert it into a MVC project. I don't quite get the first part of your question. I believe the projekt is using webforms for marketers all around.

Comment: looks like something likes this: https://github.com/BoBreiting/SitecoreItemBinding is added to your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you project has some kind of framework on top of Sitecore, the ModelBoundUserControl.

In Sitecore ASP.NET Web Forms, You can get the Current Sitecore Item with:

> Sitecore.Context.Item

If you use a Datasource you can get the Datasource Item with something like this.

```
Sublayout currentSublayout = this.Parent as Sublayout;
string DataSource = currentSublayout.DataSource;
item Item = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(DataSource)
```

If you use an very old version of Sitecore than the Datasource is a path instead of a GUID.

If you have the Sitecore Item you can access the field for example

```
string Title =  item.Fields["Title"].Value;
```

Where Title is the Field name, you can also use the GUID. Basically there is no Model you have an generic Sitecore Item Object.